# Where can I get information on QGIS beta versions?

Tags: qgis

While searching for information on some QGIS functionality on the web, I noticed several times, people using version 1.9, however this version is probably some beta (or so I thought) but I can't seem to find a download/site of it anywhere.

Then, on some other site someone wrote that there is a development version of 1.7.4. Wiki site lists only official versions, but I want to know, is there a site where some beta previews are available?

Google search yields nothing useful under 'qgis beta', 'qgis 1.9'

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: QGIS 1.9.0 avaible from OSGEO4W downloader. http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

Comment: Windows 7 and Ubuntu both

Comment: You are correct, they should have information on qgis.org which version is stable and which is beta, how you can get it etc. but **there is nothing!!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on the operating system ...

OSX:

- Nightly builds are available [here](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/nightly/qgis-mac-nightly.zip); they depend on the GDAL_complete and GSL frameworks from [Kyngchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis);
- Kyngchaos sometimes has a development version on the site too (but not as of this post).

Ubuntu / Debian Linux:

- Add the ['unstable' PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable) to your sources.list and you'll get the latest version available.

Windows:

- The [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) installer can be used in 'advanced' mode to allow the development versions to be installed.

Comment: Yes... i ve used osgeo4w installer on windows of course, but didn't notice that option, thanks

Comment: the listing of 'unstable' PPA indicates, that it's still 1.8 (at this moment), so thats not the beta. The ubuntugis repositories always seem to be far behind development, also concerning newer Ubuntu versions. The only "real" beta for Linux seems to be the debian-nightly repository: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#263-Master

Answer (score 1):

If you've install QGIS before,a repo of QGIS will be automatically added,and QGIS will follow with the latest version. I've installed QGIS 1.8 before,and now it has been updated to 1.9.0